# Paste numeric values in r

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with an shinyapp that returns an evaluation of the dataframe through time. The user specifies the initial and ending year, and it will be exported into an `json` file

let's say i have this:

```
i_year <- 2000
e_year <- 2009
```

i need to paste them together so they look like this:

```
[2000,2009]
```

i've tried to `paste()`them but they turn into character, like this:

```
"2000,2009"
```

and if i turn them into a list it only returns me the first value of the year...
any ideias how to do it?

Comment: `jsonlite::toJSON(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `glue` could be useful

```
glue::glue("[{i_year},{e_year}]")
#[2000,2009]
```

Comment: it worked, but still looks like this `"periodo": "[2015, 2017]"`
and i need it without the quotation marks

Comment: @LuccaRamalho  It is not clear about the structure you wanted.  If it is a JSON, please check the comments by r2evans.  The one I showed is of `class` 'glue' and `character`

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like you don't actually want to paste the numbers together; you want to get what would be called a `list` in python. In `R` that's called a `vector` and it's a basic data type. Just use the function `c()` to concatenate the multiple numbers into a vector:

```
v <- c(i_year, e_year)
v
[1] 2000 2009

v[1]
[1] 2000

v[2]
[1] 2009
```